# window.require is not a function

Tags: reactjs, electron, jsx, ipc, tsx

my code:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');
```

[image]

Error:

> TypeError: window.require is not a function

[image]

---

I tried to use IPC communication to control the Electron window via React.

However, the error 'TypeError: window.require is not function' continues.

Setting 'node integration' to true also results in an error.
[image]

Is there a sure way to fix this error?

Also, is there a way to control the Electron window with React without using IPC communication?

Comment: The second screenshot does not show an error, but you should include the text of all errors as text, not as a screenshot of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renderer process or not, [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#requireid) is a NodeJS function to import external modules into your file, it is not something that will be on the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window) object.

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
```

Keep in mind that your current configuration is **[completely insecure](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security)**, and you should really consider using [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) with a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) file.

Answer (score -1):

Try `const ipcRenderer = (window as any).ipcRenderer`